# incrementing variable by refreshing page in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session

Hello I am trying to learn how to use symfony so I came up with an idea to make a page that shows a number that is incremented every time page refreshes. I also wanted not to use database so exercise was not so easy. I've tried to make a service that holds variable and increments it, but because of my poor understanding of symfony it didn't work :(
Then I have tried to use session but the result was the same :(( and I ran out of ideas.
What I have done until now:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Addition\GlobalKeeper;

/**
 * Class counterController
 * @package App\Controller
 * @Route("/")
 */

class counterController extends AbstractController
{
    private $Gcounter;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Gcounter = new GlobalKeeper();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function Counter (){
        $this->Gcounter->startfordummy();
        $this->Gcounter->increment();
        return $this->render('home\insides.html.twig',
        [ 'num' => $this->Gcounter->getCounter()]);
    }
}
```

/////

```
<?php
 



namespace App\Addition;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class GlobalKeeper
{
    public $session;
    public function __constructor(){
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        if(null !==$session->get("test")) $session->set("test",0);
    }
    public function startfordummy(){
 

           $session = new Session();
            $session->start();
            if(null !==$session->get("test")) $session->set("test",0);
        }
    
        public function getCounter()
        {
            return $this->session->get("test");
        }
    
        public function increment()
        {
            $this->session->set("test", $session->get("test") + 1);
        }
    }
```

also this code results in **Call to a member function set() on null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#basic-usage) are a terrible thing to waste.

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/counter", name="counter")
     */
    public function counter(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $counter = $session->has('counter') ? (int)$session->get('counter') : 0;
        $counter++;
        $session->set('counter',$counter);

        return $this->render('default/counter.html.twig', [
            'counter' => $counter,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Tell your instructor that they are not only doing a terrible job of teaching you about sessions but also about how to search for information.

Comment: Thank you my friend that solved my problem :), and actually I have no instructor, but you are right i should have read docs first.